Hiding the address bar on mobile when scrolling down within a full-page iframe
Question:
When you scroll down a page on mobile, some browsers have a heuristic for hiding the browser address bar. This is nice because it gives more screen real estate "for free". The user can scroll up a bit to show the address bar again.
I have a situation where I'm embedding an iframe that takes up the full page except for a header bar which belongs to parent frame. This is necessary in order to sandbox user-written code (similar to CodePen/JSBin/etc). I'd like the browser address bar to hide when the user scrolls down within the iframe.
Extra context:

I'm in control of the top-level page, and can inject code into the embedded iframe and communicate via postMessage.
I'm willing to get quite hacky with my solution (e.g. involving postMessage between frames) if it would result in an end result that is quite robust - i.e. unlikely to randomly break scrolling/whatever in some browsers, under some conditions (e.g. user pinches to zoom on page), or after some valid update to the heuristic, etc. If it works in some browsers, but automatically/safely falls back to not having any effect in unsupported, then that's fine.
Any "interventions" within the iframe shouldn't interfere with the user code in a way that is likely to be relevant to the vast majority of web apps. E.g. a postMessage to the parent is fine, since it is very unlikely to interfere with user code.
Probably not relevant, the iframe is thread/performance isolated with Origin-Agent-Cluster. And the two frames have different origins.

Non-Solutions:

Making the iframe as tall as its content is not a solution, since this would result in an abnormal visual viewport size, which would affect user code that e.g. visually centers their content within the viewport, or relies on properties like window.innerHeight (and CSS vh) for calculations.
Adding fullscreen button is not a solution, but it does offer one alternative that could suit some use cases.
Running the user code at the top level (with its own subdomain) is not a solution, since I need the parent frame for important platform-level functionality.

Attempted Solutions:
I'm not optimistic that this is currently possible to achieve, given the set of requirements that I've outlined above.

My first thought was that I could just programmatically scroll the top-level frame in sync with the child frame (using postMessage from the child), such that the address bar would naturally hide itself when they'd scrolled the child frame far enough. But unfortunately (in Android Chrome, at least), the user agent does not hide the address bar based on programmatic scrolling - probably for security/anti-deception reasons.

My second thought was that I'd have to tell the embedded iframe to set overflow:hidden; on document.scrollingElement, so that the overscroll triggers the parent frame scroll, which triggers the user agent to hide the address bar, and then maybe I could detect that with Visual Viewport API, and tell the iframe to re-enable scrolling. Even if that would work, this is definitely pushing the limits of the "do not interfere with user code" rule. Ideally it would be the parent that decides that the iframe is not scrollable until the address bar has disappeared. But there's also the problem of knowing if the address bar will actually disappear at all, and when it will start to disappear, since I don't think the address bar hiding happens right away - this complicates things a lot.


So, it seems like you'd need something extremely hacky to get this working. I'm hoping that there's eventually be a browser-standards-supported way of doing this, and part of my reason for posting this question despite being quite pessimistic is so that I'll hopefully get notified when it does become possible.

It's a browser feature that is under the direct control of the user and their browser settings. A website can not take control of it away from the user for obvious security reasons!

If I have this correct, you want to disable the iframe from scrolling, until the page has scrolled up enough to remove the browser chrome from the page.
My suggestion would be to set the scrolling=“no” attribute on the iframe then watch the page via the onScroll event and the VisualViewport API to detect when the page has scrolled enough. You can the set scrolling=“auto” on the iframe or just remove it.
Technically the scrolling attribute was deprecated over a decade ago, but the CSS working group still has not got around to implementing the same functionality and all modern browsers still happily support it.

Much nicer than disabling scrolling from within the iframe! One problem is that when scrolling="no" is removed mid-scroll, the page jerks to a halt (which is almost immediately since the address bar is not very tall). User needs to raise finger, and begin a new vertical swipe to continue scrolling down the page. There are touchmove events happening in the iframe even when halted though, so maybe the full solution here involves a postMessage to the iframe (which I control) telling it to use the touchmoves to scroll until the next touchend -- assuming there's not a more simple way?

Not that I know of, my knowledge of this comes from maintaining a library called iframe-resizer, that will size the iframe based on it's content. So I've never faced the issue with changing this mid scroll.
